# Question on volume of swimming pool

Tags: volume, area, geometry

Swimming pool is of length 20m, wide 5m and height of the swimming pool increase from the 1.6m to 4.4m.

What is the volume of swimming pool?

How I approached:
Area of swimming pool = Area of cube + Area of prism

Area of cube = l * b * h

So

Area of cube = 20 * 5 * 1.6
Are of prism = ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No calc needed here:

$20\times5\times1.6$ for the cube $= 160$.

$20 \times 5 \times \frac{ 4.4 - 1.6 }2$ for the prism $= 140$
(just take the average of the two heights since the bottom is flat, if it were curved then we get into calc).

Total is $300$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Edward :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the height $h$ increases linearly with respect to its length $l$, 
i.e. height $h=1.6+2.8 (l/20)$
the volume 
corresponding to the infinitesimal region with height $h$ is $ 5 h dl$.
Thus total volume is 
$$\int_{0}^{20} 5 hdl=\int_{0}^{20} 5( 1.6+2.8 (l/20) )dl=160+140=300.$$